# Change a value in my UserModel (class) based on a userid

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I have a UserModel:

```
class UserModel {

var uid: String?
var username : String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
var dateOfBirth: String?
var registrationDate: Int?
var isFollowing: Bool?
var accessLevel: Int?
var onlineStatus: Bool?

init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
    uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String
    username = dictionary["username"] as? String
    email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    dateOfBirth = dictionary["dateOfBirth"] as? String
    registrationDate = dictionary["userRegistrationDate"] as? Int
    accessLevel = dictionary["accessLevel"] as? Int
    onlineStatus = dictionary["onlineStatus"] as? Bool
    }
}
```

And I also have a value like [12ih12isd89 : True]

I want to change the value "onlineStatus" for the user "12ih12isd89" to True and I thought the right way to do this is updateValue(*:forKey:). But my class UserModel does not have updateValue(*:forKey:).

How can I use this in my existing model?

Edit:

How I get the data:

```
func fetchAllUsers (completion: @escaping ([UserModel]) -> Void) {

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var model = [UserModel]()

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("users")

    dispatchGroup.enter()

    docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in

        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let dic = document.data()
            model.append(UserModel(dictionary: dic))
        }
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(model)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your object initialized? Can you provide more code

Comment: i have added the fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you need to find the right object in the array and update the property

```
let dict =  ["12ih12isd89" : true]
var model = [UserModel]()

if let user = model.first(where: {$0.uid == dict.keys.first!}) {
    user.onlineStatus = dict.values.first!
}
```

Depending on what ["12ih12isd89" : true] really is you might want to change the access from `dict.keys.first!` that I used

Answer (score 1):

If your value dictionary contains more than one user, you can use a for loop like this:

```
var model = [UserModel]()

//Some initalization ...

let values =  ["12ih12isd89" : true]

for (k, v) in values {
    model.filter({$0.uid == k}).first?.onlineStatus = v
}
```